# fab position on fragment startup diffrent from his position on preview android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

I'm trying to add fab button to my layout in order it will serve as search button. I want to locate it at the bottom right corner of the layout when a little piece of will be out of the layout.

on my preview screen it looks fine (as I wanted it will look) :
[My preview screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaMWT.png)

but, when running the app the fab location is different:
[the running app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDgrc.jpg)

here is my layout xml :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/departure" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/actvDepartureAdd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Departure From"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textColor="#e8e9ff"
                android:textColorHint="#e8e9ff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/landing" />

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/acTvLandingAdd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Landing At"
                    android:textColor="#e8e9ff"
                    android:textColorHint="#e8e9ff" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etDepartureDateAdd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Departure Date"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#e8e9ff"
                android:textColorHint="#e8e9ff" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgBackDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etBackDateAdd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Back Date"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#e8e9ff"
                    android:textColorHint="#e8e9ff" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/person" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Passengers"
                android:textColor="#e8e9ff" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etNumOfPassengers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#e8e9ff" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Round Trip"
                android:textColor="#e8e9ff" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/chkIsDirect"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:text="Direct Only" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSearchFlight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/search_flight"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/chkIsDirect"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Use `layout_gravity` instead `layout_anchorGravity`

Answer (score 0):

in the FAB tag
try change `layout_margin` to `layout_marginRight`

Comment: better use `layout_marginEnd` instead of `layout_marginRight`

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_page_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/app_tool_bar">

        </include>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_post_btn"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/floating_add_btn"

            app:fabSize="normal" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: ok, so wrap my xml with  RelativeLayout  did the work for me. thanx